# what is rediffmail and hotmail host name and port no?

Tags: php

Im using for rediff:

$mail->Host = 'smtp.rediffmail.com'/'smtp.rediffmail.com'/;(i tried both)

$mail->Port = 25;

and for hotmail:

$mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';

$mail->Port = 25/587; (i tried both)

but the response i get is...

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

wat is d problem?? or is der any othe problem???

Comment: Are you sure this is not a local firewall issue? Can you connect to *any* SMTP server?

Comment: yes i hav done it for yahoo and gmail and they worked successfully...

Answer (score 1):

This thread may help for hotmail: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=1093155

Looks like TLS is required (*not* SSL)